# Prove a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**Show** **that** if $f(x)=15+\prod_{j=1}^{14}(x-j)^2$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My thought**: I have seen and known how to deal with $f(x)=1+\prod_{j=1}^{14}(x-a_j)^2$, in which $a_j$ is pairwise different integers. I think the difficulty is caused by the difference between $1$ and $15$. $15$ has two kinds of factorization $3\times5$ and $1\times15$ while $1$ has only one.

---

For the second case, supposed that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.  W.l.o.g. $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are **monic** and $\deg(g)<=14$.
Firstly notice that $$f(x)>0 ,\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$$
$f(x)$ has no real root so $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have no real root and are **positive**. Then from $g(a_j)h(a_j)=1$, we know $g(a_j)= h(a_j)=1$. So as $g(x)\neq1$,$$g(x)-1=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_{14})$$Then $\deg(h)=14 $ and $h(x)$ should also be $(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_{14})+1$, but this time $f(x)$ is not equal to $g(x)h(x)$, which yields a contradiction.

Comment: suggest you show how the one you already know works out.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you show how exactly you have tried to solve the problem (or what the methos is for the more simple problem), and where the method fails for this case. This could help people better help you fill in the gap in that proof, or tell you if it's a dead end.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Please wait me a few hours, then I will organize the thought and edit proof of the second case.

Comment: For the second case, supposed that f(x)=g(x)h(x) in Z[x], g and h are monic. Firstly notice that f>0 so g,h>0. then g(a_j)h(a_j)=1,  g(a_j)=1= h(a_j).
w.l.o.g. deg(g)<=14, g(x)-1=(x-a1)…(x-a14),
then h(x) has to be (x-a1)…(x-a14)+1 but this time f(x) is not equal to g(x)h(x), which yields a contradiction.

Comment: I copy/pasted your comment into the question body, which is where it was supposed to go. Do that yourself in the future! Also, please proofread it.  Unfortunately I find it unconvincing. May be try and make that argument clear to yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your help and helpful comment!  I proofread carefully and try to improve the formatting. But I'm very sorry that I haven't found the unconvincing point. Could you tell it more clearly？